# Storing trial period date

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, nsuserdefaults

I'm implementing a trial then subscribe model into my app which allows the user to use the app for free for 14 days, then at the end of the trial it'll alert them that the trial ended and they need to subscribe to continue use.

I'm doing this settings an `NSDate` object in `standardDefaults` the first time the app is opened. Then it compares the current date with the stored date, and compares the returned time interval to the number of seconds in 14 days.

My question is this: Do `standardDefaults` stay in memory if the user deletes the app?  If not, how can I prevent a user from deleting then redownloading the app to restart the trial period?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apple is quite proud about their **sandboxing** concept and the fact, that if a app is deleted, all the data will be deleted.

The only way of ensuring this information won't be lost will be to save it to a **Database** on a server and periodical check from your app.

This as technical solution. But make sure, if Apple will allow this in there **AppStore** if you plan to release it there.

Apple forbids trial versions, though I am not sure, if you could deliver in-app purchased content free for a while and later start billing.

But the main rule is: what ever was given to the user for free must stay free.

Comment: Welp, good job putting up road blocks apple. Thanks for the insight

Comment: It's not really a road block, just change your thinking a little. Give some functionality for free, and then charge for in-app purchases if they want more.

Answer (score 2):

There are some apps that have trial periods for certain features. Look at the Puffin Browswer or ChessFree they both offer features that expire. Puffin allows for flash support (actually really cool feature!) and after a few days that feature is removed. Although the rest of the browser is still accessible the main purpose of it is removed.

ChessFree gives you points that you can use for different things, lessons, playing games, taking moves back, etc... I am not sure what happens when you run out of points but it appears that you cannot really do anything anymore.

If I were to implement something like this I would just save a variable in the keychain telling how many days they have left or the date they installed it (as a string). That way it will not be deleted if the app is uninstalled (keychain items stay stored even if the app is removed, so just always check/decrement/increment that as you wish). I would probably keep some features available to users that reach the expired time limit (like Puffin) but I honestly believe that is up to you.

Comment: note that the appstore guidelines also state, that if the user has more than one device — or buys a new —, he must be able to install an app on all of these. your approach would allow the trial for all device independently. but technical interesting. +1

Comment: @vikingosegundo Ah, I was not aware of this. Yeah in that case a private database would be your best option. Thanks for sharing that!